# Getting req.param undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Expressjs version 4.I am getting 'undefined' on req.param. Here is my example  :
app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var newdata = require('./routes/new');
........................
......................
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use('/new', newdata);
```

./routes/new

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('newdata', {
        title: 'Add new data'
    })
});

router.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.param['email']);
    res.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

newdata.html

```
<form action="/new" role="form" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
```

I also tried with `req.body` and `req.params` , but the answer is still same.

Comment: Have you verified that your form is actually being sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and not `multipart/form-data` somehow?

Comment: you have post not get..thats why.

Comment: params.. not param

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`req.params` Refers to the variables in your route path.

```
app.get("/posts/:id", ...

// => req.params.id
```

Post data can be referenced through `req.body`

```
app.post("/posts", ...

// => req.body.email
```

*This assumes you are using the `bodyParser` middleware.*

And then there is `req.query`, for those `?query=strings`.

---

You can use `req.param()` for either of the 3 above. The look up order is `params`, `body`, `query`.

Comment: `req.param()` the function already checks `req.params` (the "variables in your route path"), `req.body`, and `req.query`.

Comment: Hi , 
Suppose "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/:deviceType" is my request .
could you please tell me how to check "deviceType" against undefined?

Comment: Why `req.param()` is empty for me (using query string)?

Comment: This answer is super awesome ! POST worked for me with req.body.fieldName

Comment: @nowk your solution is great, But When I have implemented it, I'm stuck with the error **Cannot read property 'productId' of undefined**

here is the code

`router.get('/:productId', (res, req, next )=>{
const id = req.params.productId
if (id === 'gift-cards'){

    res.send('you invoked Giftcards ID')
}
else {
    res.send(`You entered the ${id} ID`)
}
})`

Answer (score 8):

[param](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.param) is a function, not an object. So you need to use `req.param('email');`

Comment: That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I'm not sure why there is negative feedback as this solved my problem perfectly. I was following some old (or just plain wrong?) examples which used param like an object, but this guided me to the right path.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone experiencing similar issues make sure to use **params** instead of param.

```
// Correct way
req.params.ID

// Wrong way
req.param.ID
```

Comment: OP stated in question: "I also tried with `req.body` and `req.params`, but the answer is still same."

Comment: but his code sample has param not params

Answer (score 2):

I also face the problem when I want to access `req.params.id` but I solved it by

index.js(main)

```
app.use('/addRoom', route);
```

router.js(router)

```
route.post('/:id',(req,res)=>{});
```

this works for me

Answer (score -2):

Two types are parameter are present
1. query (req.query.('name defined in route'));
2. path (req.params.('name defined in route));