# GET request body parameters undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to retrieve the parameters of a GET request as follows but anything I try logs out as 'undefined':

**GET**

```
// Find a list of Players
$scope.find = function() {
    $scope.players = Players.query({limit: 50});
};
```

**Middleware**

```
//Players service
angular.module('players').factory('Players', ['$resource',
function($resource) {
    return $resource('players/:playerId', { playerId: '@_id'
    }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}
]);
```

**End Point**

```
exports.list = function(req, res) { 

Player.find().sort('-created').limit(req.body.limit).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, players) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(players);
    }
});
};
```

Comment: You cannot send body with `GET`. Use `POST` instead

Comment: `req.param` is what you want not `body`

Comment: So change `Players.query` to `Players.save`? This would result in `POST` correct?

Comment: Wahoo... `req.query.limit` is what I need. This [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548929/getting-req-param-undefined) my question after investigating your response @BlakesSeven thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my request is a `GET` I need to attain the parameters (within the query string) using `.query`:

```
Player.find().sort('-created').limit(req.query.limit).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, players) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        res.jsonp(players);
    }
  });
};
```

This answer was greatly helpful [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548929/getting-req-param-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

A good discussion on GET with message body - [Is this statement correct? HTTP GET method always has no message body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216567/is-this-statement-correct-http-get-method-always-has-no-message-body)

In short, the behavior of servers when using message body with GET would probably not be consistent.