# why I am getting undefined when I try to access on my property in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I have sent data from frontend to backend when I console what type of requests I have gotten I can see the data is showing into the console but when I try to access those properties I got undefined. I have also tried with a query, body but both get undefined when I try to access the property.

[image]

Backend code:

```
   // DELETE SHORT URL
        app.delete('/delete/:shortUrl', async (res, req) => {
            console.log(req);
            console.log(req.params, 'req.params');
        })
```

Frontend:

```
 // DELETE 
    const deleteUrl = (id) => {
            fetch(`http://localhost:5000/delete/${id}`, {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }).then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.deletedCount) {
                        alert('Order Deleted')
                        // const remainingOrders = orders.filter(order => order._id !== id)
                        // setOrders(remainingOrders)
                    }

                })
                .finally(() => setLoadings(false))
    
    }
```

Comment: Well, you can follow this thread. Might help you,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548929/getting-req-param-undefined

Comment: `async (res, req) => {` to `async (req, res) => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Express [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html), the route callback's parameters (req & res) are reversed, so you should have:

```
app.delete('/delete/:shortUrl', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req);
  console.log(req.params, 'req.params');
})
```